# Setting band level in Equalizer not working

Tags: java, android, audio

I am writing an app that plays 4 mp3 files simultaneously using 4 MediaPlayer objects. I have added 3 custom knobs to control bass, mid, and treble using 4 equalizers, each attached to its specific MediaPlayer. I have verified that I am passing the correct values (in Millibels) to setBandLevel for each as specified, but I don't hear any difference in sound when spinning the controls. I have added the relevant code below.

One thing I noticed that seems really odd is that the Equalizer method I am calling expects a short, but the frequency range upper limits come back as high as 6,000,000 millibels. I may be missing something here, but a short in android is 2^16 which should mean an upper limit of 64k.

> public void setBandLevel(short band, short level)

The code runs without hitting exceptions and I have traces all values to verify each frequency is within its band's range, but I get no variance in sound when I spin the control knobs. I have tested this on K, L and M with the same results.

I appreciate any insight into this.

```
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
        AdView adView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        //initialize views
        initializeViews();
        setInstrumentNames();

        mediaPlayer1.start();
        mediaPlayer2.start();
        mediaPlayer3.start();
        mediaPlayer4.start();
        // Start the songtime thread and remember its object so it can be stopped legally
        play();
        setEqualizer();
        setupKnobButtons();
    }

    public void setEqualizer() {
        eq1 = new Equalizer(0, mediaPlayer1.getAudioSessionId());
        eq2 = new Equalizer(0, mediaPlayer2.getAudioSessionId());
        eq3 = new Equalizer(0, mediaPlayer3.getAudioSessionId());
        eq4 = new Equalizer(0, mediaPlayer4.getAudioSessionId());
        if (eq1 != null && eq2 != null && eq3 != null && eq4 != null) {
            int z = eq1.setEnabled(true);
            int c = eq2.setEnabled(true);
            int d = eq3.setEnabled(true);
            int e = eq4.setEnabled(true);
            // The number of bands is usually 5 but could be up to 13
            num_bands = eq1.getNumberOfBands();
            // The band range will always return the min and max
            // Gets the level range for use by setBandLevel(short,short)}. The level is expressed in
            // milliBel. Return the band level range in an array of short integers. The first element is the lower
            // limit of the range, the second element the upper limit.
            // --- THIS IS FOR THE FULL RANGE OF ALL BANDS ---///
            range = eq1.getBandLevelRange();
            min_level = range[0];
            max_level = range[1];
            Log.d(TAG_BANDLEVELS, "min level = " + min_level + " max level = " + max_level);

            // Loop through all the bands ( usually 5 ) and create 2 arrays
            // ( one for lower limit of each band and one for the upper )
            for (int i = 0; i < num_bands; i++) {
                freq_range = eq1.getBandFreqRange((short) i);
                freqRangeLowerLimit.add(freq_range[0]);
                freqRangeUpperLimit.add(freq_range[1]);
                    Log.d(TAG_BANDLEVELS, "freqRangeLowerLimit = " + freq_range[0] +
                        " freqRangeUpperLimit = " + freq_range[1] + " band  = " + i);
            }
        }
    }
    private void setBandLevels(int percentage, int new_level1, int new_level2, int nBand) {
        if (eq1.hasControl()) {
            eq1.setBandLevel((short) nBand, (short) new_level1);
        }
        else
            Log.d(TAG_BANDLEVELS, "EQ 1 DOES NOT HAVE CONTROL");
        if (eq2.hasControl()) {
            eq2.setBandLevel((short) nBand, (short) new_level1);
        }
        else
            Log.d(TAG_BANDLEVELS, "EQ 2 DOES NOT HAVE CONTROL");
        if (eq3.hasControl()) {
            eq3.setBandLevel((short) nBand, (short) new_level1);
        }
        else
            Log.d(TAG_BANDLEVELS, "EQ 3 DOES NOT HAVE CONTROL");
        if (eq4.hasControl()) {
            eq4.setBandLevel((short) nBand, (short) new_level1);
        }
        else
            Log.d(TAG_BANDLEVELS, "EQ 4 DOES NOT HAVE CONTROL");
        // Mid and Treble use 2 bands (Mid = 2nd and 3rd Treble = 4th and 5th
        if (nBand == PlayFragment.BAND_BASS || nBand == PlayFragment.BAND_TREBLE) {
            try {
                eq1.setBandLevel((short) (nBand+1),  (short) new_level2);
                eq2.setBandLevel((short) (nBand+1),  (short) new_level2);
                eq3.setBandLevel((short) (nBand+1),  (short) new_level2);
                eq4.setBandLevel((short) (nBand+1),  (short) new_level2);
            } catch (Throwable ex2) {
                ex2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setupKnobButtons() {
        RoundKnobButton rnbBass = (RoundKnobButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.btRoundBass);
        rnbBass.SetListener(new RoundKnobButtonListener() {
            TextView tvEQBass = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvEQBass);

            public void onStateChange(boolean newstate) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "New state:" + newstate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onRotate(final int percentage) {
                tvEQBass.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tvEQBass.setText("\n" + percentage + "%\n");
                        // Bass only uses the first band
                        int lower1 =  freqRangeLowerLimit.get(0);
                        int upper1 =  freqRangeUpperLimit.get(0);
                        int new_level1  = lower1 + ((upper1 - lower1) * percentage/100);
    //                    new_level1 /= 1000;
    //                    int new_level1 = calc1/100;
                        int lower2 =  freqRangeLowerLimit.get(1);
                        int upper2 =  freqRangeUpperLimit.get(1);
                        int new_level2  = lower1 + ((upper2 - lower2) * percentage/100);
   //                     new_level2 /= 1000;
  //                      int new_level2 = calc2/100;
                        setBandLevels(percentage, new_level1, new_level2, BAND_BASS);
                        Log.d(TAG_BANDLEVELS, "Band = Bass " +  "New Level1 = " + new_level1 + "New Level2 = " + new_level2 + " Percentage = " + percentage);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: I still don't have an answer on this. I have tried adding BassBoost and that isn't changing the tone either. I notice that many of the code examples are using a service to encapsulate their sound. My next attempt to to implement a service to do the audio, but the docs I have read say it is OK to use MediaPlayer like this on the main thread because the MediaPlayer classes use their own threads under the covers. I have tried using only one MediaPlayer.  I have tried adjusting priorities. My volume controls are working fine in the MediaPlayer, just none of the AudioEffects. Still stumped.

Comment: I fixed this problem. I had been assuming that I needed to control the bands in each equalizer by using the band frequency ranges. After analyzing other posts, I  learned that each band can be controlled by the min_range and max_range assigned for ALL bands in the equalizer... Code below for anyone who may have hit the same snag:

Comment: This can be closed now.

Comment: if you found an solution you should put it here as an answer, not as comment, so other people can see that this question has a solution and get help from it too.

Comment: dear @JoeBarry I don't see the code :( can you please put it as answer not a comment. thank you in advance.